# How to install Play Store App on Android Studio Emulator Google API 23

Tags: android-emulator

I selected this emulator from the newest version of Android Studio AVD,

Google API 23

I have selected the latest version of android API 23. Because it says "with Google APIs", I thought that it would actually include all the Google apps, including Play Store so that I can install apps like Facebook.
But I can't see any Google Apps in it.
How do I install Gapps on Android Studio Emulator with Google API23?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from API24 Google publishes emulator images with Google Play. Download it from CLI:

```
yes | sdkmanager "system-images;android-24;google_apis_playstore;x86" \
    "system-images;android-25;google_apis_playstore;x86" \
    "system-images;android-26;google_apis_playstore;x86" \
    "system-images;android-27;google_apis_playstore;x86" \
    "system-images;android-28;google_apis_playstore;x86_64"
```

Or download it from AndroidStudio:

[image: Download google play emulator image]

Answer (score 0):

You can install a particular system image via the terminal, with the following command:

```sh
sdkmanager "system-images;android-30;google_apis_playstore;x86"
```

Trying to install the system images via the terminal, produced the following error:

```sh
'sdkmanager' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

If you get this error, then you need to locate where `sdkmanager` is installed and add that folder to your `PATH` environment variable.

For me this was located under `<AndroidSDK>\tools\bin`

However, even after doing this I still got the following error.

```sh
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 5 more
```